# Is there a way to get react router to *NOT* refresh api data on return to page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, fetch, react-router-dom

So I have a page that takes 5 seconds to load the data from an API. I put the results in a table.  The user clicks one of the rows, it takes them to another route with details about that row.  They dont see what they want and return to the 1st page.
The page refreshes and it re-pulls the API data for another 5 seconds.
Is there a way to call the first page back and the data/state still be there?  Seems like it works like that in react-native.
Obviously I can implement pagination / caching etc..  But just curious if there's something Im missing.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can't offer any direct help, but perhaps useEffect could work well for you here?  Putting the API call within the useEffect block will only call it when your specific conditions are met  (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).  Feel free to post some code if you need more specific help!

Comment: I was looking at it more conceptually so didnt look at it as a code problem.  I havent used Hooks yet, are you saying that hooks will give me features that dont previously exist?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to be clear here. React is not SPA. It appears SPA in nature only because it can be packaged to be so, with cli tools like CreateReactApp. Alternatively, React can be Server Side Rendered (SSR) using tools like [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/).

As noted by @CarsonEsplin, a useEffect with the right dependency array should help. Manual caching in some storage is possible, but should not be necessary unless you plan to use that same data again without fetching in another react component. In which case, application state management tools like [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) should help.